# Variadic template evaluation

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates

I was wondering if its possible to pass functions to the variadic template to have some kind of logic to enable or disable especific parameters.
Let me explain better. I have an Entity-Component-System system in C++11 with variadic templates, where the entities are simple ids, the components are data and/or small logic functions and all the logic happens inside the systems.
The systems get the needed entities searching with a variadic template the entities that have a list of specific components (I don't use ids to check for the components), something like:

```
var entities = m_world.get<position, direction, acceleration>();
```

But I was wondering if its possible to do something like:

```
var entities = m_world.get<position, direction, acceleration, Except<rotation, whatever>>();
```

To filter the entities that have a specific component.

The code to my ECS is freely available here: https://github.com/arajar/ecs

Thanks.

Comment: 1. m_world.get<position, direction, acceleration>() is equal to the m_world.search<...>() function in your ECS code? With your second line you want to find all entities that have position, direction and acceleration but don't have the attributes rotation and whatever?

Comment: Have you tried to implement a m_world.search_not<...>() function? which works similar to search<...>() but finds all excluding entities with the given template parameters.

Comment: I wanted to avoid that, implementing the search_not<...>() then i would have to also call the search<...> and then filter the results from one list with the ones from the other. If there is no other solution then yes, I will do that.

Comment: I looked at your ecs code on github. Your current implementation of m_world.search<...> seems to only support 1 or 2 parameters of components. Using m_world.search<pos, dir, vel>() will end in an compilation error.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that! I created the code and never fully tested it in a proper working environment. I will try to fix that tonight at home :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very likely possible. To archive `Search<Include<int, float>, Exclude<std::string, double>>::search();`. You could write following code:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

template<typename ...Args>
class Search;

template<>
class Search<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<>> {
public:
    static void search() {
    }
};

template<typename T, typename ...Include, typename ...Exclude>
class Search<std::tuple<T, Include...>, std::tuple<Exclude...>> {
public:
    static void search() {
        std::cout << "include: " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
        Search<std::tuple<Include...>, std::tuple<Exclude...>>::search();
    }
};

template<typename T, typename ...Exclude>
class Search<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<T, Exclude...>> {
public:
    static void search() {
        std::cout << "exclude: " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
        Search<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<Exclude...>>::search();
    }
};

template<typename ...Args>
using Include = std::tuple<Args...>;

template<typename ...Args>
using Exclude = std::tuple<Args...>;

int main() {
    Search<Include<int, float>, Exclude<std::string, double>>::search();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I was looking for!